# Captcha in GWT Widget

Tags: gwt, widget, captcha, simplecaptcha

I'm looking for a Captcha (SimpleCaptcha or JCaptcha) widget for GWT. I've found examples online, but they all use servlets to generate and validate the Captcha. Are there any client-only Captcha implementations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CAPTCHA has to be generated server-side because of the implicit security. There's no way to be positive that anything client-side is secure. Since GWT client code gets turned into Javascript, it's feasible that it can be modified. Potential for modification means potentially insecure content. That's why implementations [like this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/06/add-captcha-gwt-application.html) all use server-side code to generate, pass down as an image, and validate all CAPTCHAs.