# Hiding AJAX with JSON communication from user

Tags: ajax, json, gwt, security

We are currently working on a web client that communicates with the server using AJAX with JSON. The client is based on gwt, and communication is over https.

The communication can be easily inspected by browser tools - is there some reasonable approach to hide this from the user, i.e. securing the protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than standard authentication and encryption techniques used by all browsers, whatever method you come up with, it must be initiated by your JavaScript client. This means that a good hacker can deconstruct your JavaScript and figure out how you submit data.

Security usually deals with either third parties trying to intercept communication or pose as legitimate users, or malicious users trying to get access to where they are not supposed to. Once you verified that a user is legitimate, why would you try to hide user's data from the user? Maybe you can describe your use case.

EDIT:

The only way to prevent bots is to ask a question that only a human can answer (e.g. Captcha) somewhere in the workflow (i.e. before submitting important data). It's usually annoying for users, but there is no other way. Since you build a gaming platform, ask your designer to come up with some fun verification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a gaming platform. The main reason is probably to not allow easy bot development. Of course we cannot prevent people from developing bots that just use the browser and simulate clicks, but with an open protocol this takes things to another level.

Comment: As long as you don't have a trusted (hardware) platform (like e.g. a gaming console), you can always only try to obfuscate or hide the data within other data. Every kind of encryption needs some kind of secret (a key or something similar) - and if the user has access to that secret, then (s)he can decrypt it, too.

Answer (score 1):

Just to Round off Security Checklist

1) HTTPS - you have got it set up already :)

2) Json and XSS/XSRF Web Security -

```
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/security_for_gwt_applications#json-xsrf
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/security_for_gwt_applications#json
```

3) BOT attacks - A decent captcha - [Captcha in GWT Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506100/captcha-in-gwt-widget)

4) Miscellaneous - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/_gViO5aZ-WQ